# QR code control working all the time

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, qr-code

I'm using [JeffWilcox QR control (QR Scanner)](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/wpqr-control/), but I have one issue with this control. When I launched a page with this control, it's working all the time, even I click back button and I am in main menu. Do you know how can I handle situation like: if user click back button the QR Scanner control will stop working ?

Working:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        nameOfControl.StopScanning();
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're navigating through pages, there are some events triggered when you enter or exit a page, such as `OnNavigatedFrom` (when you left the page) or `OnNavigatingFrom` (just before leaving the page) or `OnNavigatedTo` (when you entered a page).

You can find more information about page navigation events in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Windows.Controls.Page_methods(v=vs.105).aspx).

You can take advantage of these events to solve your issue. As it seems, create a handler for the `OnNavigatingFrom` event in the page where you have the QR control, to stop it.

Comment: I found method StopScanning(), but it's not working. I've added code to my first post

Comment: I guess it has to be something about the QR Control... The navigation event handler is plain and simple...